# Electro magnet strength to weight ratio

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, estimation

I was wondering.
How would I work out how strong a magnet would have to be to support my weight.

Comment: It depends on your weight and how smart you are using that magnet. I would say that, unless you are very heavy, less than one lbs. of magnetic material should suffice. Having said that... don't do anything stupid with magnets! For one thing... any magnet that can hold your weight might hurt you pretty badly if you get your fingers caught between the two pieces... it's like someone of your weight jumping on your finger with metal shoes!

Comment: @jakolaka This also depends on what magnetic materials you are using (i.e. the details of your magnetic endeavor). For example, you could be asking how much standard neodymium magnet of a particular thickness you will need to support your body weight hanging on a flat iron plate, possibly attached to a ceiling (assuming you and the neodymium are inseparable).